# Error while querying for data in postgreSQL

Tags: database, python-3.x, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

In my book review `flask` webapp I am trying to add the search functionality. Users should be able to search for the book by either isbn number, title of the book or author of the book. 
However, I get this error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

And this is my code for that functionality in `application.py`

```
@app.route('/search',methods=['GET','POST'])
def search():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("search.html")

    else:
        text = request.form.get("search")
        books = db.execute("SELECT * from books WHERE isbn = :isbn OR title = :title OR author = :author",
                {"isbn":text},{"title":text},{"author":text})
        if books is None:
            return render_template("notfound.html")
```

And this is my books table in the database which has 5000 books added to it.

```
Table "public.books"
 Column  |         Type          | Collation | Nullable |                Default                 
---------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------
 isbn    | character varying(30) |           | not null | 
 title   | character varying(30) |           | not null | 
 author  | character varying(30) |           | not null | 
 year    | character varying(30) |           | not null | 
 book_id | smallint              |           | not null | nextval('books_book_id_seq'::regclass)
```

This is the how my database is defined:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, session, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from passlib.apps import custom_app_context as pwd_context
from flask_session import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

app = Flask(__name__)

# Check for environment variable
if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")

# Configure session to use filesystem
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Set up database
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

Comment: what database libarary are you using?

Comment: postgreSQL database with flask

Comment: show how `db` is defined

Comment: I added it now in the edit

Comment: ah sqlalchemy.  sorry can't help you. but someone else might be able.